# NHibernate Transactions: Is the INSERT-UPDATE_DELETE order for a batch documented somewhere?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, batch-file, transactions

Preface: This question is a derivative of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12616962/109941), speaking specifically about `NHibernate` instead of `Hibernate`.

> As to Hibernate, javadoc to org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(EventSource) says:
>
> Execute all SQL and second-level cache updates, in a special order so that foreign-key constraints cannot be violated:
>
> 1. Inserts, in the order they were performed
> 2. Updates Deletion of collection elements
> 3. Insertion of collection elements
> 4. Deletes, in the order they were performed

My Questions:

1. If it applies to Hibernate, does this order apply to NHibernate too?
2. Is this deterministic order documented somewhere?

Also - If this behavior is DBMS-specific, I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of [NHibernate 3.3](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) is in detail describing the steps when the Session.Flush is called (point 9.6). In case of `session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;` this is how the transaction batch will be executed:

- http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

The steps are:

- all entity insertions, in the same order the corresponding objects were saved using ISession.Save()
- all entity updates
- all collection deletions
- all collection element deletions, updates and insertions
- all collection insertions
- all entity deletions, in the same order the corresponding objects were deleted using ISession.Delete()

I am mostly using SQL Server (2008) and can say that this is working this way..