# Cascade.Remove don't work for OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a unidirectional OneToOne relation like

```
@Entity   
public class Citizen
{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     protected Long id;

     @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     protected FileEntity photo;
     ...getters and setters....
}

@Entity
public class FileEntity
{
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     protected Long id;
}
```

Then when I go to remove a Citizen object the following error appear:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update o delete on <> violates the foreign key fk_citizen_file_id in the table <>

Why this happen??

Comment: Does the instance you are calling delete on have a reference to a FileEntity?  How did you read in the Citizen before calling remove on it?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate performs delete operations in the database in [the order they were performed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861675/4754790).

Thus, either remove the `FileEntity` manually before removing the `Citizen`, or make the foreign key nullable in the database.