# JPA Hibernate query execution order inside transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, one-to-many, many-to-one

Is the execution order of the queries whithin a transaction always the same of the jpa method call order in the code?

I have an entity `Element` and the entity `Order` .
On the `Order` entity I have a `@ManyToOne` relation that is Unidirectional .
On the `Order` table there is a FK reference to `Element` table but on the `Element` entity there is no `OneToMany` relationship to order.

The `deleteElement` method starts by calling a method to remove all the order of an element (`elementService.deleteOrderElement(element);` it's called on a diffrenrent `EJB`).

Then It removes the element itself `entityManager.remove(element);` .

**My problem is that sometimes in production enviroment I recieve a foreign constraint violation error, as if the `delete element` query it has been called before the `delete order` queries.
Is possible that Hibernate just mixeup the queries since there is only a Unidirectional reletionship?**
I was not able to replicate the error in test enviroment.

This is an extraction of the method code. The actual method is more complex but this is the critic part.

```java
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void deleteElement(Set<Long> elementIds,String utente) {
        .....
        Long id = null;
        Iterator<Long> it = idDpi.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Element element =entityManager.find(Element.class, it.next());

            ...
            elementService.deleteOrderElement(element);
            ....
            entityManager.remove(element );
            log.debug("Aggiorna tabella auditing - rimozione dpi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into a similar issue in my code recently.
There is not so much information about it but looks like your issue is in hibernate SQL execution order when flushing to the database.
It's mentioned in documentation of [AbstractFlushingEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html#performExecutions%28org.hibernate.event.spi.EventSource%29).

There is some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616336/how-is-hibernate-deciding-order-of-update-insert-delete).
And a more detailed discussion about it [there](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/about-the-order-of-sql-execution-when-flushing-to-the-database/1425).

Basically, the fix is to call *flush()* manually or use *update* in my case since I had *delete* and then *insert* operations which caused *a duplicate key violation exception* since hibernate executed insert first.